# Oracle sqlldr timestamp format headache

Tags: oracle, format, timestamp, sql-loader

I'm struggling to get `sqlldr` to import a csv data file into my table, specifically with the field that is a timestamp.

The data in my csv file is in this format:

```
16-NOV-09 01.57.48.001000 PM
```

I've tried all manner of combinations in my control file and am going around in circles. I can't find anything online - not even the Oracle reference page that details what all the date/timestamp format strings are.

Does anyone know where this reference page is, or what format string I should be using in my control file for this timestamp format.

For reference, this is what I've most recently tried:

```
load data
infile 'kev.csv'
into table page_hits
fields terminated by "~" 
( ...
  event_timestamp TIMESTAMP "dd-mmm-yy hh24.mi.ss", 
...)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can try this format:

```
event_timestamp TIMESTAMP "dd-MON-yy hh.mi.ss.ff6 PM"
```

You can browse all available formats in the [SQL reference documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).

Comment: Thanks Vincent, that page is just the ticket.